# Kill Cat After Background Process Ends

Tags: bash, cat

Running a C# program with mono under Cent OS. There is a fifo that allows external input to go into this program.

I also have `cat` to accept input from the screen session the mono program is running in.

```
#! /bin/bash -
echo "Starting server"
mono --gc=sgen Server-CLI.exe < $fifo &
echo $$ > $PIDFILE
cat > $fifo
echo "Server stopped. Cleaning up"
rm -f $fifo
rm -f $PIDFILE
```

How can I make `cat` exit whenever the mono program exits? Right now if the mono program exits, `cat` is still running so the script never reaches the 2nd `echo`.

Comment: Flagging this for animal abuse.

Comment: Whoops! Didn't even recognize that title...

Comment: Nah, it's fine, we programmers have our little peculiarities, everyone knows that.

Comment: Well, at least your username wasn't 'Curiosity'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the PID of `mono`. Run `cat` in the background and save its PID. `wait` for the PID of `mono`. When this is satisfied, `kill` the PID of `cat`.

```
mono &
monoPID=$!
cat &
catPID=$!
wait "$monoPID"
kill "$catPID"
```

Comment: This works! One side effect though, is that the screen session gets spammed with ">" repeatedly (making output unviewable). I am guessing it is some side effect from running `cat` in background. Any clue on how to stop this? Thanks for answering my initial question though!!

Comment: @Dequ: Are you doing `cat > "$fifo"` instead of my lazy placeholder version. I should have spelled out the commands completely. You shouldn't be getting ">" in the output.

Comment: Yes I am using `cat > "$fifo"`. I now believe that it is caused by the Server-CLI.exe program as a result of running `cat` in the background. For whatever reason, Server-CLI.exe has a ">" at the bottom signifying where input is typed. Never-mind this issue anymore, as it seems only a change in the Server-CLI.exe code will fix it. Thanks for affirming that I shouldn't be getting ">" as a result of `cat`, it made me go back and find something I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it from $!

```
(cat > $fifo)& 
pid=$!

kill -9 "$pid"
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat` doesn't die immediately when `mono` exits because it's waiting on its `stdin`. As soon as it has some data to send, it will die with a `SIGPIPE` signal, because the pipe no longer has a process connected to the other end.

Unfortunately I'm not a hardened `select` guru so I don't know offhand whether it's possible to write a "better" version of `cat` that checks both `stdin` and `stdout` and dies as soon as `stdout`'s other end is closed.